# Python:Loop through .csv of urls and save it as another column

Tags: python, python-2.7

New to python, read a bunch and watched a lot of videos. I can't get it to work and i'm getting frustrated.

I have a List of links like below:

```
"KGS ID","Latitude","Longitude","Location","Operator","Lease","API","Elevation","Elev_Ref","Depth_start","Depth_stop","URL"
"1002880800","37.2354869","-100.4607509","T32S R29W, Sec. 27,   SW SW NE","Stanolind Oil and Gas Co.","William L. Rickers 1","15-119-00164","2705"," KB","2790","7652","http://www.kgs.ku.edu/WellLogs/32S29W/1043696830.zip"
"1002880821","37.1234622","-100.1158111","T34S R26W, Sec. 2,   NW NW NE","SKELLY OIL CO","GRACE MCKINNEY 'A' 1","15-119-00181","2290"," KB","4000","5900","http://www.kgs.ku.edu/WellLogs/34S26W/1043696831.zip"
```

I'm trying to get python to go to "URL" and save it in a folder named "location" as filename "API.las".

ex) ......"location"/Section/"API".las
    C://.../T32S R29W/Sec.27/15-119-00164.las

The file has hundred of rows and links to download. I wanted to implement a sleep function at the also to not bombard the servers.

What are some of the different ways to do this? I've tried pandas and a few other methods... any ideas?

Comment: `import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('MeadeLAS.csv')
links = data.URL
file_names = data.API
for link, file_name in zip(links,file_names):
    file = pd.read_csv(link).to_csv(file_name+'.las', index=False)`

Comment: @mortz forgot to tag

Comment: Do you want to store the link in the .las file? Or do you want to store the contents of the link in the .las file?

Comment: @Mortz I want the to store the contents of the link as a .las

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do something like this

```
for link, file_name in zip(links, file_names):
    u = urllib.urlopen(link)
    udata = u.read()
    f = open(file_name+".las", "w")
    f.write(udata)
    f.close()
    u.close()
```

If the contents of your file are not what you wanted, you might want to look at a scraping library like `BeautifulSoup` for parsing.

Comment: I need it to follow the link which ques a download and I want it to save as the value in the column API. From how I read your suggeston this wouldnt be the case.

Comment: That is precisely what the code is trying to do. `udata` holds the contents of `link` and writes it to a `file_name` that comes from your API column. Try it. If you are trying to achieve something totally different then please edit your question accordingly

Comment: Sorry I was confused in the way i read the code. I ran it an was able to make it work. Only edit was putting quotes around the W in the open function when opening the file to write. Also, the links download a .zip so saving it to a .las before unzipping is an issue, but using 7 zip i was able to batch unzip the files

Comment: Great. Mark whichever answer helped you the most as the right answer for future questioners

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1 :-**

Your file has suppose 1000 rows.

Create masterlist which has the data stored in this form ->
[row1,row2,row3 and so on]

Once done, loop through this masterlist. You will get a a row in string format in every iteration.
split it make a list and splice the last column of url i.e. row[-1]

and append it to a empty list named result_url. Once it has run for all rows, save it in a file and you can easily create a directory using os module and move your file over there

**Approach 2 :-**

If file is too huge, read line one by one in try block and process your data (using csv module you can get each row as a list, splice url and write it to file API.las everytime).

Once your program moves 1001th line it will move to except block where you can just 'pass' or write a print to get notified.
In approach 2, you are not saving all data in any data structure, you just storing a single row at executing it, so it is more fast.

```
    import csv, os
    directory_creater = os.mkdir('Locations')       
    fme = open('./Locations/API.las','w+') 
    with open('data.csv','r') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
        print spamreader.next()
        while True:
            try:
                row= spamreader.next()
                get_url = row[-1] 
                to_write = get_url+'\n' 
                fme.write(to_write)
            except:
                print "Program has run. Check output."
                exit(1)
```

This code can do all that you mentioned efficiently in less time.

Comment: the file has 240,163 rows with unique urls that needs to be saved

Comment: Please use Approach 2 (i have edited it again). Don't accumulate all data in list.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little dirty, but it's a first pass at solving the problem. This is all contingent on each value in the CSV being encompassed in double quotes. If this is not true, this solution will need heavy tweaking.

Code:

```
import os

csv = """
"KGS ID","Latitude","Longitude","Location","Operator","Lease","API","Elevation","Elev_Ref","Depth_start","Depth_stop","URL"
"1002880800","37.2354869","-100.4607509","T32S R29W, Sec. 27,   SW SW NE","Stanolind Oil and Gas Co.","William L. Rickers 1","15-119-00164","2705"," KB","2790","7652","http://www.kgs.ku.edu/WellLogs/32S29W/1043696830.zip"
"1002880821","37.1234622","-100.1158111","T34S R26W, Sec. 2,   NW NW NE","SKELLY OIL CO","GRACE MCKINNEY 'A' 1","15-119-00181","2290"," KB","4000","5900","http://www.kgs.ku.edu/WellLogs/34S26W/1043696831.zip"
""".strip() # trim excess space at top and bottom

root_dir = '/tmp/so_test'

lines = csv.split('\n') # break CSV on newlines
header = lines[0].strip('"').split('","') # grab first line and consider it the header

lines_d = [] # we're about to perform the core actions, and we're going to store it in this variable
for l in lines[1:]: # we want all lines except the top line, which is a header
    line_broken = l.strip('"').split('","') # strip off leading and trailing double-quote
    line_assoc = zip(header, line_broken) # creates a tuple of tuples out of the line with the header at matching position as key
    line_dict = dict(line_assoc) # turn this into a dict
    lines_d.append(line_dict)

    section_parts = [s.strip() for s in line_dict['Location'].split(',')] # break Section value to get pieces we need

    file_out = os.path.join(root_dir, '%s%s%s%sAPI.las'%(section_parts[0], os.path.sep, section_parts[1], os.path.sep)) # format output filename the way I think is requested

    # stuff to show what's actually put in the files
    print file_out, ':'
    print '    ', '"%s"'%('","'.join(header),)
    print '    ', '"%s"'%('","'.join(line_dict[h] for h in header))
```

output:

```
 ~/so_test $ python so_test.py 
/tmp/so_test/T32S R29W/Sec. 27/API.las :
     "KGS ID","Latitude","Longitude","Location","Operator","Lease","API","Elevation","Elev_Ref","Depth_start","Depth_stop","URL"
     "1002880800","37.2354869","-100.4607509","T32S R29W, Sec. 27,   SW SW NE","Stanolind Oil and Gas Co.","William L. Rickers 1","15-119-00164","2705"," KB","2790","7652","http://www.kgs.ku.edu/WellLogs/32S29W/1043696830.zip"
/tmp/so_test/T34S R26W/Sec. 2/API.las :
     "KGS ID","Latitude","Longitude","Location","Operator","Lease","API","Elevation","Elev_Ref","Depth_start","Depth_stop","URL"
     "1002880821","37.1234622","-100.1158111","T34S R26W, Sec. 2,   NW NW NE","SKELLY OIL CO","GRACE MCKINNEY 'A' 1","15-119-00181","2290"," KB","4000","5900","http://www.kgs.ku.edu/WellLogs/34S26W/1043696831.zip"
 ~/so_test $
```

Comment: here is a link with a sample of the output [link](http://www.kgs.ku.edu/oracle/las40033.txt)

Comment: The part of your code that creates the directory path is correct, however i cannot get the code to actually create the folder paths. Also, I need the code to follow the URL, start the download, and save the file as API.like @Mortz above. So given the directory you provided it would look like  /tmp/so_test/T32S R29W/Sec. 27/15-119-00164.las.